# How I can call an api from MVC .net 4.7.2 using Microsoft Identity Planform (Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I am following a tutorial from microsoft docs and I have created an api with Microsoft Identity Platform  using Azure AD in asp.net core 5.

The tutorialI followed shows how to call an api from asp.net core 5, and I have done that part but now I want to call the api from asp.net 4.7.2. Since I am new to apis and example I am finding are not using Microsoft Identity platform to call an api secured by microsoft identity

Can someone point me to document, tutorial, or code which shows me how I can call the api. Code should be written in asp.net not core.

I have done some part but stuck on calling the api.

See the below code

Api methods:
I have already setup the api and web app in Azure portal and configured permission to 2 of the scope.

**Method in api**.
GetCategory()
GetCatalog()

```
 private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification 
  notification)
    {
        notification.HandleCodeRedemption();

        var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();

        var signedInUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);


        try
        {

            var apiScope = "catalog.Read, Category.Read";
            string[] scopes = apiScope.Split(' ');

            var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
               //rest of the code to call the api for both scope
               // and if i have to do add some code to controller
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but here it goes.
Once you get the `accessToken` with required scope, you just need to add it as Authorization Header when you make a call to the API:

```
const string Scheme = "Bearer";
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Scheme, result.AccessToken); 
var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)
```